# Substring and command's output assignment to a variable in DOS batch programming

Tags: variables, batch-file, substring, findstr

I'm trying to capture the time before I execute a command. Up to now, I have this code (I am using Windows 7 Pro) :

```
time < nul | findstr  /r [0-9][0-9]*.*$
```

The above prints:

```
The current time is: 13:02:23.89
```

My questions are:

1) How do I get rid of the "The current time is: " string?

2) How do I assign the remaining value **13:02:23.89** to a variable?

Unfortunately, I **cannot** put other utilities in this computer, such as resource kits, cygwin, powershell, and other third-party executables. The solution must involve just DOS batch commands.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`echo %time%` - there is already variable holding current time :-)

For more - help set

Comment: Yes, my bad! I found about it after I posted. Too late!! But thanks a lot for your help too